# How to check if CSS selectors are on the same HTML tag line

Tags: javascript, html, css

Without using `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`, how can I check if CSS selectors are on the same HTML line.

```js
let tag = "div";
let id = "some_id"
let classs = "another_class"

if (document.getElementsByTagName(CSS.escape(tag)) || document.getElementById(CSS.escape(id)) || document.getElementsByClassName(CSS.escape(classs))) {
  console.log("cool");
} else {
  console.log("not cool");
}
```

```html
<div id="some_id" class="some_class some_other_class"></div>
<img class="another_class"></img>
```

It should return `not cool` as the CSS selectors aren't on the same line, whereas if I used the selector `div#some_id.some_class`, it would return `cool`.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `querySelector`?

Comment: Both [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) return an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), so both calls will evaluate to true in the if condition. Check for `HTMLCollection.length` on these instances.

Comment: That is not even valid HTML. The `img` element cannot have an end tag.

Comment: @Olian04 I'm guessing because it's a school project.

Comment: @Olian04 Curiosity is getting the better of me man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved ID first, as that is unique, then compare the other qualifications to it.

```js
let tag = "div";
let id = "some_id"
let classs = "another_class";

let idMatch = document.getElementById(CSS.escape(id));

if (idMatch &&
    idMatch.tagName == tag.toUpperCase() &&
    idMatch.classList.contains(classs) ) {
  console.log("cool");
} else {
  console.log("not cool");
}
```

```html
<div id="some_id" class="some_class some_other_class"></div>
<img class="another_class"></img>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName(CSS.escape(tag)) == document.getElementById(CSS.escape(id))` is never going to evaluate to `true`.

Comment: above answer by @jacob thomas doesn't work but, he's on the right track

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp: thanks for pointing that out. i resolved the arrays

Comment: what happens when you have more than one div?

Comment: @DCR: edited. Resolved ID first, since that is unique, then compares tags and classes.

Comment: @DCR: i appreciate being pushed into a better answer =)